# Problems resizing a Layout

Tags: android, resize

Well, I'm trying to resize my Layouts using a custom method, but I'm having problems on different devices. Works in my mobile and on my tablet, but when I try to open the app on the mobile of my friend this happens:

[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHmte.jpg)

My device:
I can add only a single photo.
[Image mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYKko.jpg)

Methods to rescale:

```
public final static int DEV_WIDTH = 480;
public final static int DEV_HEIGHT = 800;

public static int toDensityPx(Activity context, int targetPx){

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    Point resolution = new Point();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        display.getRealSize(resolution);
    } else display.getSize(resolution);

    int deviceWidth = resolution.x;

    Log.e("DENSITY", String.valueOf(displayMetrics.densityDpi));
    Log.e("DENSITY XXHIGH", String.valueOf(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH));
    Log.e("WIDTH DEVICE", String.valueOf(deviceWidth));

    int scale = scale(deviceWidth, targetPx);

    Log.e("RESULT", String.valueOf(scale));
    Log.e("TOTAL", String.valueOf((scale*targetPx)));

    int result = 0;

    switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){

        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: result = (int)(scale/0.75f);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: result = targetPx;
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: result = (int)(scale/1.5f);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH: result = (int)(scale/2f);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH: result = (int)(scale/3f);
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH: result = (int)(scale/4f);
            break;
    }
    return result;
}


public static int scale(int deviceWidth, int targetPx){

    double scale = 0;

    if(deviceWidth < DEV_WIDTH) scale = (double)DEV_WIDTH/deviceWidth;

    else if(deviceWidth == DEV_WIDTH) scale = 1;

    else scale = (double)deviceWidth/DEV_WIDTH;


    return (int)((scale*targetPx));
}
```

Code where I'm trying to add the scale:

```
PercentRelativeLayout Percent = (PercentRelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.percent1);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = Percent.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = Scaler.toDensityPx(getActivity(), 380);
    params.width = Scaler.toDensityPx(getActivity(), 380);
    Percent.setLayoutParams(params);

    FrameLayout Frame = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageprofile);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsfr = Frame.getLayoutParams();
    paramsfr.height = Scaler.toDensityPx(getActivity(), 190);
    paramsfr.width = Scaler.toDensityPx(getActivity(), 190);
    Frame.setLayoutParams(paramsfr);
```

The method looks good because is resizing all the text on the app and all works fine, but is not the same when I try to resize my Layouts.

Comment: I think you should estimate the device width and height,then use  relative size.like 190/device.width

Comment: Is the same rescale method for both, I mean, If you divide the native height (device where i'm developing) with the height of the device where the app is running, will be the same if you use width. @sanemars

Comment: I can't understand why is all working when i use the app on my tablet and is not when i try to use it on the mobile of my friend, should be the same result. @sanemars